# C# Negative Number Result

Tags: c#

I am trying to create randomly 20 numbers between 1 and 100. I want to achieve this with declaring a delegate and event. I check if any of the 20 numbers is bigger than 50, then I multiply the nubmers, if not sum all numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        // Delegate tanımla
        public delegate int MyDelegate(int[] arr);
        public event MyDelegate OnResultCalculated;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            // 1-100 arasında 20 adet rastgele sayı üret
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(20).ToArray();

            // Eğer 50'den büyük sayı varsa çarp, yoksa topla
            int result = numbers.Any(x => x > 50) ? p.Multiply(numbers) : p.Add(numbers);

            // Event'i tetikle
            p.OnResultCalculated?.Invoke(numbers);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public int Multiply(int[] arr)
        {
            return arr.Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a * b);
        }

        public int Add(int[] arr)
        {
            return arr.Sum();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working but sometimes I get a negative result. What is the problem?

Comment: You probably have an overflow. The maximum value for an int is about 2 billion. When you multiply a lot of numbers the result can get bigger than that.

Comment: You're probably having an integer overflow.  The maximum value for an `int` is 2,147,483,647.   Change all instances of `int` to `long` and see if that helps.

Comment: @possum, nothing change but thank you. thank you   -derpirscher too, i just reduced the created 20 numbers to 5 and work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments tell you, it is possible that `int` is not big enough for your result. The highest possible value is 100^20. But this is just theoretical. So your `int` is to small for such numbers. The max. possible value of int is 2.147.483.647. If you calculate this value +1, it will result in the smallest value of int: -2.147.483.648. This is the reason why you may have a negative value: If the value is higher than the max. value of int, it will start from the smallest again.

[image]

One possible way is to reduce the random value, like you did. If you change int to long, the possibility of running into this issue is smaller, but still there.

If you combine both it will be a possible solution. Change the result type to `long` and just use 5 values. 100^5 is smaller than `long.MaxValue`.